# Vector of Vectors created with the vec! macro contain different capacities

Tags: vector, rust

I have a vector`matrix_a`, which contains 3 vectors, and it is initialized with the `vec!` macro.

Every vector should have a capacity of 3, due to `Vec::with_capacity(dim)`, but only the last vector has a capacity of 3. The other vectors have a capacity of 0.

Can someone explain why that is?

```
fn main() {
    let dim = 3;
    let matrix_a: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![Vec::with_capacity(dim); dim];

    for vector in matrix_a{
        println!("Capacity of vector: {}", vector.capacity());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Capacity of vector: 0
Capacity of vector: 0
Capacity of vector: 3
```

Comment: Alright, that's a fun one...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec!.html), `vec!` is defined as:

```
macro_rules! vec {
    ( $ elem : expr ; $ n : expr ) => (
        $ crate:: vec:: from_elem ( $ elem , $ n )
    );
    ( $ ( $ x : expr ) , * ) => (
        < [ _ ] > :: into_vec (
            $ crate:: boxed:: Box:: new ( [ $ ( $ x ) , * ] )
        )
    );
    ( $ ( $ x : expr , ) * ) => ( vec ! [ $ ( $ x ) , * ] )
}
```

In your case, it means that:

```
vec![Vec::with_capacity(dim); dim]
```

is expanded into:

```
std::vec::from_elem(Vec::with_capacity(dim), dim)
```

The definition of `Vec::from_elem` is hidden in the documentation, but can be [found in the source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/vec.rs.html#1287):

```
pub fn from_elem<T: Clone>(elem: T, n: usize) -> Vec<T> {
    unsafe {
        let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        let mut ptr = v.as_mut_ptr();

        // Write all elements except the last one
        for i in 1..n {
            ptr::write(ptr, Clone::clone(&elem));
            ptr = ptr.offset(1);
            v.set_len(i); // Increment the length in every step in case Clone::clone() panics
        }

        if n > 0 {
            // We can write the last element directly without cloning needlessly
            ptr::write(ptr, elem);
            v.set_len(n);
        }

        v
    }
}
```

And this where the heart of the mystery is solved:

- the element is cloned `n - 1` times, for the `n - 1` first elements of the vector, and then moved into the `n`-th slot.
- cloning a vector does not clone its capacity, only its elements.

Thus the result you get is exactly as intended, if not as expected.

Answer (score 13):

As stated, this is because `vec![x; y]` clones the value. To avoid this, you can instead `collect` your vector:

```
let matrix_a: Vec<Vec<i32>> = (0..dim).map(|_| Vec::with_capacity(dim)).collect();
```

This seperately initializes each element, giving you complete allocations.